# speech recognition and ROS

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone installed pocketsphinx and ROS for speech recognition

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202172/speech-recognition-and-ros/) by [Gulfboy64](https://answers.ros.org/users/21534/gulfboy64/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have look at [this Pi Robot blog entry](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0022/).

However, this is rather outdated, assuming ROS Electric.

I highly recommend obtaining the latest copy of [ROS by Example - Volume 1](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-indigo-volume-1/ebook/product-22015937.html), which has a chapter dedicated to this ("9. Speech Recognition and Synthesis") - see [Table of Contents](http://www.pirobot.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/toc-long-hydro.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0